# Creating a Stripe Subscription

Tags: haskell

I have some working Haskell code in a Yesod application that is responsible for creating a new paid Stripe subscription for a user.

Although it works, I'm not pleased with the walking indentation that appears as a result of nested `Either` case matches.

```
module Handler.Purchase where

import           Import
import           Web.Stripe
import           Web.Stripe.Customer
import           Web.Stripe.Plan
import           Web.Stripe.Subscription

postPurchaseR :: Handler Html
postPurchaseR = do
  -- I will need to keep a reference to the user later
  _ <- requireAuth

  -- I will need to keep a reference to the Stripe token later
  _ <- runInputPost $ ireq textField "stripeToken"

  -- I hard-code the secret key, which I'm fine with for now
  let config = StripeConfig $ StripeKey "<redacted>"

  -- Here's where things get hairy...
  customer <- liftIO $ stripe config createCustomer
  case customer of
    Left err -> do
      setMessage $ toHtml $ show err
      redirect (AppR :#: ("subscribe" :: Text))
    Right Customer { customerId = cid } -> do
      plan <- liftIO $ stripe config $ getPlan (PlanId "PRO")
      case plan of
        Left err -> do
          setMessage $ toHtml $ show err
          redirect (AppR :#: ("subscribe" :: Text))
        Right Plan { planId = pid } -> do
          subscription <- liftIO $ stripe config $ createSubscription cid pid
          case subscription of
            Left err -> do
              setMessage $ toHtml $ show err
              redirect (AppR :#: ("subscribe" :: Text))
            Right _ -> do
              setMessage "Subscription successful. Thanks!"
              redirect AppR
```

As I understand it, I should be using `ExceptT` instead of having all that nesting, but I'm not sure how that works. Correct use of `ExceptT` will probably obviate the need for me to define how to handle those three failures each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can use `ExceptT`:

```
  -- I hard-code the secret key, which I'm fine with for now
  let config = StripeConfig $ StripeKey "<redacted>"
  let stripe' :: (FromJSON (StripeReturn a))
              => StripeRequest a -> ExceptT StripeError Handler (StripeReturn a)
      stripe' = ExceptT . liftIO . stripe config

  -- Here's where things get hairy...
  r <- runExceptT $ do
    Customer {..} <- stripe' createCustomer
    Plan {..} <- stripe' $ getPlan (PlanId "PRO")
    stripe' $ createSubscription customerId planId
  case r of
    Left err -> do
      setMessage $ toHtml $ show err
      redirect (AppR :#: ("subscribe" :: Text))
    Right _ -> do
      setMessage "Subscription successful. Thanks!"
      redirect AppR
```

I used [RecordWildcards](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#record-wildcards) so that the intermediate variables (e.g. cid and pid) aren't necessary. 
You'll also need to enable `FlexibleContexts` because of the way `stripe` is defined in the library.

Comment: Real nice. Thanks also for the `RecordWildcards` tip!